# Azure Workbook not fetching data from custom endpoint despite CORS enabled

Tags: azure-functions, azure-monitor, azure-monitor-workbooks

I'm using an Azure Function App as a custom endpoint for my Azure Workbook.

However, I've noticed that my Workbook is unable to fetch data from the function app, complaining that CORS isn't enabled:
[image]

Yet CORS is enabled, and for the sake of testing, I've allowed all origins:
[image]

Is there something else I can do? Or another thing to debug?

TIA!

P.S: I've tried from my Postman, the endpoint is working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this little setting was enabled for some reason:
[image]

So, the OPTIONS preflight request wasn't going through. Anyways, problem is now solved.

Thanks for the heads up @John

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to look at the exact errors coming out in F12 tools network and console tools. The problem we have is that if *anything* goes wrong with CORS in the browser, the browser literally just returns "0" to the caller.  We don't have any further information to show you, but the *browser* might in the debug tools.

One thing that *might* be the case is that your CORS implementation is very sensitive to headers, so you might need to check that "don't send standard correlation headers" option in the screenshot.